# java-apns INVALID_TOKEN response

Tags: java, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I'm using **java-apns** library for send push notification messages. I send `token_id` to APNS server and receive response **INVALID_TOKEN**. So my question is what algorithm APNS server use for this response? I think it would be better to check this token_id on my side and if it's ok then push message to this token. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

APNS does not offer any API to check whether a specific token is valid. An algorithm would not be useful either, as `INVALID_TOKEN` means not only a malformed token, but it is also returned when the token does not match any registered app, or the app has been uninstalled, or you used a development token to communicate to production APN server or vice versa.

The correct way of handling a invalid token is to send the message and, if you get an `INVALID_TOKEN` error, delete the token from your own server and don't use it anymore.

There is, however, the [Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW12) that you should query regularly in order to get tokens that have been unregistered recently.